# Any way to change bluetooth default folder to sender device name?

Tags: bluetooth

I have a print bureau and I receive a lot of photos via bluetooth in our computers... I was using Windows to do that but I tried Linux Ubuntu and it works better. I bought a computer only to do my bluetooth receives and was perfectly.

Here is my question: Has any way to receive files (even in Download folder) but for each sender device name, the Ubuntu create a folder using the sender device name and put the files inside it?

Thanks in advance.